# U-net with non-square input images

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I am trying to implement U-net in Python using Keras with my biomedical data. Therefore I am using the [this](https://github.com/bnsreenu/python_for_microscopists/blob/master/074-Defining%20U-net%20in%20Python%20using%20Keras.py) code as an example.

However, my problem is, that my data is non-square and it's really big: `3736 x 2800`.

Does anyone has an idea how to perform U-net on non-square input data?

When I try to run the code it always says:

> ValueError: A Concatenate layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 466, 466, 128), (None, 467, 467, 128)]

Comment: It's actually not about sizes being equal, it's about sizes being divisible by 2 many times (remember that UNet gradually downsamples the data by factor 2 for a few times). 3736 can be divided by 2 three times, until it reaches 467, then your layers shapes are messed up. You could try to resize the image to something close, but more divisible, e.g. 3712, which is 29*2^7. The second dimension could be 2816 (which is 11*2^8)

Comment: Resize all images before feeding them to your network. `img=tf.image.resize(img,(128,128))` or whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyS.Larionov! Saved me :P